# Getting input constantly using python multithreading

Tags: python, multithreading

I want to write a program which will print a string every second on the other hand it will allow user to write text, I have the code snippet below. My problem is everytime a new line is printed, input line is also disturbed. Is there a way to seperate the output lines from the input line?

```
import time
from thread import start_new_thread

def heron():
  while 1:
  time.sleep(1)
  print "some text"

start_new_thread(heron,())
c = raw_input("Enter text>")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I doubt you can do this without [`curses`](http://docs.python.org/library/curses.html). There might be another way, but I don't think it would be very pretty. There's a basic how-to [here](http://docs.python.org/howto/curses.html#curses-howto).